# How to print HTML document along with CSS style programmatically using C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing a C# project that should have a feature of printing HTML pages. I used WebBrowser control's Print() function. Confusingly, the function strips CSS styles from the HTML page while printing! Can you please tell me an alternative solution that prints HTML page along with CSS styles?

Comment: There's no such thing as C#.NET. It's just "C#".

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Mr. Saunders!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As none of the answers helped me, I tried hard finding out the actual problem. Now, I can figure out what actually is wrong.

The problem is with my Internet Explorer's page setting! Don't get it? Okay, let me explain it. Microsoft .NET's WebBrowser class just wraps the unmanaged Internet Explorer's functionality to form a managed version. So, if anything was wrong in IE, it would also affect the WebBrowser class.

[image]

In my case, my Internet Explorer's 'page setting' was not configured to print out background colors and images. All I gotta do is to just click the check box which is labelled as 'Print Background Colors and Images'. That's it! :) Now, my application happily prints out the HTML page with CSS styles!

Anyways, I thank all the three guys who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CSS applied, when you view the website in the WebBrowser?
It might be, that the site simply has a different CSS style for printing?
In general, the WebBrowser should print with CSS, because its just the IE encapsulated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Hilgarth! Please, see my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create different css for printing which will contain media="print" tag instead of media="screen".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Hrvach. Nope! I didn't add that thing to my CSS style. Let me check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding:

```
 @media screen, print {
   //css goes here
  }
```

to your css file? this will specify the css is used for on screen and printing

Comment: Thanks for the answer, WraithNath. Nope! I didn't add that thing to my CSS style. Let me check that out.

Comment: No Problem, I hope it helps you. the @media is good for hiding things from printed pages also